# Undefined path extension using pathinfo at PHP

Tags: php, undefined

If i want to get the extension of a URL with pathinfo function, i do this:

```
<?php
 $path_parts = pathinfo($url);
 echo $path_parts["extension"];
?>
```

And what's my surprise that Apache shows the following notice:

```
Notice: Undefined index: extension in ...
```

How can i deal with it?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us what's a content of `$url`? If it does not contain `extension=val` you'll keep getting this notice. You can hide them with not showing using error_reporting, but it's awful solution. :)

Comment: url can be any URL, for example: http://youtube.com/watch?v=g3OsdbvzZz4&feature=g-all-lik
But yeah, the problems is that this URL hasn't got extension :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to get only extension use this:

```
$extension = pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
echo $extension;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function getExtension($url)
{
  $url = explode('.',$url);
  return $url[count($url)-1];
}
```

You could use this manual function to retrieve it .

Comment: nice way to express it. "split the string by '.' and give me the last token". if I understand correctly, it will still take the full name as the extension if there is no extension to begin with(one token).

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party but you'd get an undefined index while doing an `echo $path_parts["extension"]` if the target is a directory.